# Como realizar um CRUD em C# com MySQL e ADO

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, crud, ado

Eu preciso fazer o relacionamento entre tabelas 1:N e N:N.

Tabela `produto`:

```
public int id {get; set;}
public string produto {get; set;}
public list<tamanhos> tamanhos {get; set;}
```

Tabela `tamanhos`:

```
public int produto_id {get; set;}
public string tamanho {get; set;}
```

Os produtos podem ter inúmeros tamanhos. Como fazer um CRUD em MySQL em C# dentro desse cenário? Eu sei fazer todas as operações do CRUD para tabelas isoladas ou 1:1.

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer? Do jeito que sua pergunta está ela será fechada.

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, neste caso você terá que ter um CRUD para Tamanhos, os Tamanhos deverão ser cadastrados antes de você tentar cadastrar um Produto.
Em produto você só fará a referência com os tamanhos, neste caso será um relacionamento N:N e no banco de dados você irá precisar de uma terceira tabela para manter esse relacionamento.
Na tabela Tamanho você irá cadastrar os tamanhos, depois na tabela Produtos você cadastra os produtos e deverá existir uma tabela ProdutosTamanhos onde será informado o Id do produto e o Id do tamanho, algo parecido com Vendas e ItensVenda que é um exemplo bastante conhecido.

Comment: Muuuito obrigado!!!